# My Fail2Ban filter doesn't appear to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fail2ban

I'm trying to use the `fail2ban-regex` command to test my filter and regex, but it doesn't seem to be having any luck. I used a tutorial to demonstrate how to use the Devise gem with Rails to log failed logins.

Here's my `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/core.conf` file:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]
failregex = ^\s*(\[.+?\] )*Failed login for '.*' from <HOST> at $
```

and then here's what I have in my `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` file.

```
[core]
enabled = true
filter  = core
port    = http,https
logpath = /home/rails/Documents/rails_app/devise.log
bantime = 3600
findtime = 600
maxretry = 2
```

And here's an example output from the `devise.log` file that Rails created:

```
# Logfile created on 2018-09-26 16:19:41 -0500 by logger.rb/61378
E, [2018-09-26T16:19:41.353620 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'ekjtherkjh@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:19:41Z
E, [2018-09-26T16:27:17.469743 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:17Z
E, [2018-09-26T16:27:19.706783 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:19Z
E, [2018-09-26T16:27:21.504956 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:21Z
E, [2018-09-26T16:27:23.193147 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:23Z
```

It's exactly what was used in the tutorial. However, when I submitted invalid login attempts, nothing happened.

Here's the result of my `fail2ban-regex` command:

```
[myuser:ubuntu:/etc/fail2ban/filter.d]$ fail2ban-regex /home/rails/Documents/rails_app/devise.log "^\s*(\[.+?\] )*Failed login for '.*' from <HOST> at $"

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : ^\s*(\[.+?\] )*Failed login for '.*' from <HOST> at $
Use         log file : /home/rails/Documents/rails_app/devise.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [13] ExYear(?P<_sep>[-/.])Month(?P=_sep)Day(?:T|  ?)24hour:Minute:Second(?:[.,]Microseconds)?(?:\s*Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 13 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 13 missed
[processed in 0.02 sec]

|- Missed line(s):
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:19:41.353620 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'ekjtherkjh@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:19:41Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:27:17.469743 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:17Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:27:19.706783 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:19Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:27:21.504956 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:21Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:27:23.193147 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:23Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:27:24.959032 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:24Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:27:26.661292 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:26Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:27:28.297408 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:28Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:27:30.179503 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:30Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:27:31.940616 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:31Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:32:42.579173 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:32:42Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:32:44.817088 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:32:44Z
|  E, [2018-09-26T16:32:46.660918 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:32:46Z
```

Not sure why this isn't working. Any suggestions by chance? I've tried to manipulate my regex, but still no luck.

**EDIT**

It literally seems like Fail2Ban is broken or I'm just completely screwing up the Regex. I've reduced my `devise.log` file to just a single line containing an IP address, and reduced my filter down to just this:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]
failregex = <HOST>
```

and it STILL doesn't even find the IP address:

```
[myuser:ubuntu:/etc/fail2ban/filter.d]$ fail2ban-regex /home/rails/Documents/rails_app/devise.log core.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : core, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use      datepattern : Default Detectors
Use         log file : /home/rails/Documents/rails_app/devise.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 1 missed
[processed in 0.01 sec]

|- Missed line(s):
|  172.16.38.1
`-
```

Answer (score 1):

In your log you have lines that look like this:

```
E, [2018-09-26T16:27:17.469743 #12157] ERROR -- : Failed login for 'kjelkjer@gmail.com' from 172.16.38.1 at 2018-09-26T21:27:17Z
```

And your regex is missing the ending with this part: **2018-09-26T21:27:17Z** at the end of the lines. So you need to modify your regex as follows:

```
failregex = ^.* (\[.*\])* ERROR -- \: Failed login for '.*' from <HOST> at .*$
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/QZyfdN/1/) you can test your regexes. Just remember to replace `<HOST>` with `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+` on regex site and then back to `<HOST>` in your conf files.

Let me know if it helped.